# Can I give Classnames in Tailwindcss so i can use them in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, tailwind-css

## **My Problem:**

I want to give an button a classname instead of an id, but i dont know how this would work because im using tailwind

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".my-class");

btn.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    console.log("test");

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/output.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <button class="rounded-full my-class bg-purple-500 py-2 px-5">
        test
    </button>
</body>

<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</html>
```

the error:

### **The Question:**

Is there a way to assign class names while using tailwindcss?

### **What I've tried:**

I tried to just write my own class name in the tailwind class, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your work in a [mre] - also read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  _"that doesn't work"_ is not descriptive enough of the issue to be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom class `my-class` and add it inside the class list

```
  <button class="rounded-full my-class bg-purple-500 py-2 px-5">
        test
  </button>
```

Change `submit` to `click`  in your `listener`

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".my-class");

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log("test");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

what i understand from this question is, you need event using class if button is clicked.
In addEventListener use `click`.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".my-class");

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    alert("test");
});
```

```html
<body>
    <button class="rounded-full my-class bg-purple-500 py-2 px-5">
        test
    </button>
</body>
```